Prestashop WAMPP OpenSSL error "Unable to generate private keys using openssl_pkey_new."
How can i fix this error in PrestaShop while using WAMPP "Unable to generate private keys using openssl_pkey_new. Check your OpenSSL configuration, especially the path to openssl.cafile.".

I tried making the environment variables thing but its still not working.

Did you get a solution? I too have same problem.
